# Как вывести данные в php без jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Отправляю через ajax данные, вот код

```
 function f (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", 'index.php', true)

xhr.send("name=hello"); 

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
    if (xhr.status != 200){
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }else{ 
     alert(xhr.responseText)
    }
  }
}
```

но php код ни чего не выдает, вот код

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

echo "<br/>login = ". $_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

проверяю все на wordpress,
если использовать обычную форму, все работает, но перезагружается страница..
нужно без jquery отправить данные и вывести их на странице, прошу помогите

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77438/discussion-on-question-by------php--jquery).

Comment: Не надо делать всё через опу... Почитайте инструкцию о том, как правильно строить ajax-запросы в WP: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html Да, там jquery(от которого в WP вы всё равно не уйдёте, он там нужен) . Но уж если очень хочется красоты, сделайте вызов на чистом js. Но обратите внимание, что вызыввать надо admin-ajax.php, а не index.php, и должен быть обязательный параметр action.

Answer (score 0):

подобная тема поднималась ранее:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071544/post-from-xmlhttp-with-parameters

Тебе нужно добавить заголовок, добавь код перед строкой отправки:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```